# Duda de como hacer multiples inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[image: ayuda]
Tengo  un problema cuando quiero agregar un alquiler quiero que genere varios inserts a  la tabla pagos dependiendo de la  cantidad y no se como hacerlo
Ejemplo

```
insert into Alquiler values('48265014',1000,1,getdate(),'19/11/2017',300.00, cantidad 3,1);
go
```

quiero que me aparezca asi  dependiendo la cantidad

```
insert into pagos values(1,300.00,'19/11/2017',0);
insert into pagos values(1,300.00,'19/12/2017',0);
insert into pagos values(1,300.00,'19/01/2018',0);
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Comment: Agrega también la etiqueta del motor sql que estás usando, las soluciones en mysql pueden ser distintas de las de sql server u oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías usar en este caso es un bucle, While para ser mas precisos. Seria de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @CONT AS INT;
SET @CONT = 0
WHILE @CONT < 7 -- controlas las cantidad de vueltas
BEGIN
insert into pagos values(1,300.00,'19/11/2017',0);
SET @CONT = @CONT + 1
END
```

Comment: Gracias ya me salio